# Inverse factorial summation

Tags: factorial

> Find the sum  $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \dfrac1{n!}$$

Sorry, I couldn't find the symbol for Sigma.

Sigma(1/n!)
I tried this but couldn't do it.

Any suggestions for the problem are welcome.

Comment: The sign you are searching is \sum. Is this sum finite, or infinite?

Comment: The summation is till infinity

Comment: Not really sure about the range of the sum  . Please check if the edit is correct

Comment: By the way , $e = 1 + \frac1{2!} + \frac1{3!} + \frac1{4!} + \cdots$

Comment: Hint: What is the Maclaurin series of $$e^x$$ ?

Comment: Yes it is sir .

Comment: This is a well-known number, usually designated by the letter $e.$

Comment: Your question is indeed ambiguous -- what do you mean by *finding* the sum. It's already there. The most important thing is to find out if it represents a definite number, or not. It does. Whatever is left to do is to find ways to approximate this number (which is irrational, by the way) by rationals. We know how to do all this. Check a book on calculus, or google $e.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$e^x=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\dfrac{x^n}{n!}$$ 
So for $x=1$ you have:
$$e=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\dfrac{1}{n!}$$

Answer (score 0):

The answere is the number e. Just use the Taylor-Lagrange theorem on the exponential fonction.